# How to calculate frequency of elements for pairwise comparisons of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, frequency

I have the the sample stored in the following list

```
 sample = [AAAA,CGCG,TTTT,AT-T,CATC]
```

.. To illustrate the problem, I have denoted them as "Sets" below

```
Set1 AAAA
Set2 CGCG
Set3 TTTT
Set4 AT-T
Set5 CATC
```

1. Eliminate all Sets where each every element in the set is identical to itself.

Output:

```
 Set2 CGCG
 Set4 AT-T
 Set5 CATC
```

2. Perform pairwise comparison between the sets. (Set2 v Set4, Set 2v Set5, Set4 v Set5)
3. Each pairwise comparison can have only two types of combinations, if not then those pairwise comparisons are eliminated. eg,

   ```
   Set2    Set5
   C       C
   G       A
   C       T 
   G       C
   ```

Here, there are more than two types of pairs (CC), (GA), (CT) and (GC). So this pairwise comparison cannot occur.

Every comparison can have only 2 combinations out of (AA, GG,CC,TT, AT,TA,AC,CA,AG,GA,GC,CG,GT,TG,CT,TC) ... basically all possible combinations of ACGT where order matters.

In the given example, more than 2 such combinations are found.

Hence, Set2 and Set4; Set4 and Set5 cannot be considered.Thus the only pairs, that remain are:

```
Output
Set2 CGCG
Set4 AT-T
```

4. In this pairwise comparison, remove any the element with "-" and its corresponding element in the other pair

   ```
   Output    
   Set2 CGG
   Set4 ATT
   ```
5. Calculate frequency of elements in Set2 and Set4. Calculate frequency of occurrence of types of pairs across the Sets (CA and GT pairs)

   ```
   Output
   Set2 (C = 1/3, G = 2/3)
   Set4 (A = 1/3, T = 2/3)
   Pairs (CA = 1/3, GT = 2/3)
   ```
6. Calculate float(a) = (Pairs) - (Set2) * (Set4) for corresponding element (any one pair is sufficient)

   ```
   eg. For CA pairs, float (a) = (freq of CA pairs) - (freq of C) * (freq of A)
   ```

NOTE: If the pair is AAAC and CCCA, the freq of C would it be 1/4, i.e. it is the frequency of the base over one of the pairs

7. Calculate

   ```
   float (b) = float(a)/ (freq of C in CGG) * (freq G in CGG) * (freq A in ATT) * (ATT==> freq of T in ATT)
   ```
8. Repeat this for all pairwise comparisons

eg.

```
Set2 CGCG
Set4 AT-T
Set6 GCGC
```

Set2 v Set4, Set2 v Set6, Set4 v Set6

My half-baked code till now:
** I would prefer if all codes suggested would be in standard for-loop format and not comprehensions **

```
#Step 1
for i in sample: 
    for j in range(i):
        if j = j+1    #This needs to be corrected to if all elements in i identical to each other i.e. if all "j's" are the same
                        del i 
    #insert line of code where sample1 = new sample with deletions as above

#Step 2
    for i,i+1 in enumerate(sample):
    #Step 3
    for j in range(i):
        for k in range (i+1):
        #insert line of code to say only two types of pairs can be included, if yes continue else skip
            #Step 4
            if j = "-" or k = "-":
                #Delete j/k and the corresponding element in the other pair
                #Step 5
                count_dict = {}
                    square_dict = {}
                for base in list(i):
                    if base in count_dict:
                            count_dict[base] += 1
                    else:
                            count_dict[base] = 1
                    for allele in count_dict:
                    freq = (count_dict[allele] / len(i)) #frequencies of individual alleles
                    #Calculate frequency of pairs 
                #Step 6
                No code yet
```

Comment: I don't understand step #3. How do `CGCG` and `AT-T` yield those pairs?

Comment: Every comparison can have only 2 combinations out of (AA, GG,CC,TT, AT,TA,AC,CA,AG,GA,GC,CG,GT,TG,CT,TC) ... basically all possible combinations of ACGT where order matters. In the given example, more than 2 such combinations are found. Hence, Set2 and Set4; Set4 and Set5 cannot be considered.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you mean by "freq of c" in step for the pair AAAC and CCCA? Would it be 1/4 or 1/2? That is, is it the frequency of the base over a single pair or both pairs?

Comment: What is base1  supposed to be? Also how are set2 and set4 a match considering they have no matching letters?

Comment: I have corrected "base1" statement. Set2 and Set4 are considered a match, because they meet the criteria that, it has only 2 unique combinations CA and GT..while the Set2 v Set5 have (CC), (GA), (CT) and (GC) (more than 2 unique pairs)

Comment: Is this not exactly the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072098/how-to-create-dictionaries-when-comparing-two-elements-at-a-time-in-python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In the question that you have linked, I have simplified the question, so that the core of the question get answered. You are right I should probably mark that as duplicate

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
from collections import Counter

# Remove elements where all nucleobases are the same.
for index in range(len(sample) - 1, -1, -1):
    if sample[index][:1] * len(sample[index]) == sample[index]:
        del sample[index]

for indexA, setA in enumerate(sample):
    for indexB, setB in enumerate(sample):
        # Don't compare samples with themselves nor compare same pair twice.
        if indexA <= indexB:
            continue

        # Calculate number of unique pairs
        pair_count = Counter()
        for pair in zip(setA, setB):
            if '-' not in pair:
                pair_count[pair] += 1

        # Only analyse pairs of sets with 2 unique pairs.
        if len(pair_count) != 2:
            continue

        # Count individual bases.
        base_counter = Counter()
        for pair, count in pair_count.items():
            base_counter[pair[0]] += count
            base_counter[pair[1]] += count

        # Get the length of one of each item in the pair.
        sequence_length = sum(pair_count.values())

        # Convert counts to frequencies.
        base_freq = {}
        for base, count in base_counter.items():
            base_freq[base] = count / float(sequence_length)

        # Examine a pair from the two unique pairs to calculate float_a.
        pair = list(pair_count)[0]
        float_a = (pair_count[pair] / float(sequence_length)) - base_freq[pair[0]] * base_freq[pair[1]]

        # Step 7!
        float_b = float_a / float(base_freq.get('A', 0) * base_freq.get('T', 0) * base_freq.get('C', 0) * base_freq.get('G', 0))
```

Or, more Pythonically (with the list/dict comprehensions you don't want):

```
from collections import Counter

BASES = 'ATCG'

# Remove elements where all nucleobases are the same.
sample = [item for item in sample if item[:1] * len(item) != item]

for indexA, setA in enumerate(sample):
    for indexB, setB in enumerate(sample):
        # Don't compare samples with themselves nor compare same pair twice.
        if indexA <= indexB:
            continue

        # Calculate number of unique pairs
        relevant_pairs = [(elA, elB) for (elA, elB) in zip(setA, setB) if elA != '-' and elB != '-']
        pair_count = Counter(relevant_pairs)

        # Only analyse pairs of sets with 2 unique pairs.
        if len(pair_count) != 2:
            continue

        # setA and setB as tuples with pairs involving '-' removed.
        setA, setB = zip(*relevant_pairs)

        # Get the total for each base.
        seq_length = len(setA)

        # Convert counts to frequencies.
        base_freq = {base : count / float(seq_length) for (base, count) in (Counter(setA) + Counter(setB)).items()}

        # Examine a pair from the two unique pairs to calculate float_a.
        pair = list(pair_count)[0]
        float_a = (pair_count[pair] / float(seq_length)) - base_freq[pair[0]] * base_freq[pair[1]]

        # Step 7!
        denominator = 1
        for base in BASES:
            denominator *= base_freq.get(base, 0)

        float_b = float_a / denominator
```

Comment: In # Remove elements where all nucleobases are the same, you are assuming that sample will have the same structure of only 4 bases. It can have n number of bases. I think this would be a better to add this sample1 = []
for i in sample:
    if len(set(i)) > 1:
        sample1.append(i)

Comment: (2) I am extremely sorry for the confusion but with regard to your ealier question when there is AAAC and CCCA It should be 1/4, i.e. freq over one pairs.

Comment: Also, I get this error when compiling float_b = float_a / (base_freq.get('A', 0) * base_freq.get('T', 0) * base_freq.get('C', 0) * base_freq.get('G', 0))
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero

Comment: Comment 1: I'm pretty sure I got that right -- if the entire string is made up of the first character (if it exists -- the code works for zero-length strings), delete it.

Comment: Comment #3: I have this as an initializer for `sample`: `sample = ['AAAA', 'CGCG', 'TTTT', 'AT-T', 'CATC']`. Perhaps you have something different?

Comment: Do I have to import some other tools? I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: Ah... sorry. I wrote this for Python 3. Division in Python 3 is normally floating point division instead of integer as in Python 2. I will fix this...

Comment: Sure. Is it possible to amend for Comment 2 also?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125850/discussion-between-lungj-and-biotechgeek).