# How to create dictionaries when comparing two elements at a time in Python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, frequency

I have the the sample stored in the following list

```
 sample = [CGG,ATT,CCCC]
```

.. To illustrate the problem, I have denoted them as "Sets" below

```
Set2 CGG
Set4 ATT
Set5 CCCC
```

2. Perform pairwise comparisons between Set2 v Set4, Set2 v Set5, Set4 v Set5

Consider, Set2 v Set4

3. Calculate frequency of elements in Set2 and Set4. Calculate frequency of occurrence of types of pairs across the Sets (CA and GT pairs)

   ```
   Output
   Set2 (C = 1/3, G = 2/3)
   Set4 (A = 1/3, T = 2/3)
   Pairs (CA = 1/3, GT = 2/3)
   ```
4. Calculate float(a) = (freq Pairs) - (freq Set2) * (freq Set4) for corresponding element (any one pair is sufficient)

   ```
   eg. For CA pairs, float (a) = (freq of CA pairs) - (freq of C) * (freq of A)
   ```

Do this for all pairwise comparisons

Prefer if code is in for-loop format and not comprehensions. The code attempted:

```
 for i in range(len(sample)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(sample)): 
                count_dict = {}
                square_dict = {}
                for base in list(i):  #dictionary
                    if base in count_dict:
                            count_dict[base] += 1
                    else:
                            count_dict[base] = 1
                    for allele in count_dict:
                    freq1 = (count_dict[allele] / len(i)) #frequencies of individual alleles in 'CGG'
                    for base in list(j):  #dictionary
                    if base in count_dict:
                            count_dict[base] += 1
                    else:
                            count_dict[base] = 1
                    for allele in count_dict:
                    freq2 = (count_dict[allele] / len(j)) #frequencies of individual alleles in 'ATT'
                    #Insert code to calculate frequency of pairs - I do not know how to do this
                #Step 4, Final Output for this set of pairs
                float(a1) = (freq Pairs(CA)) - (freq1(C)) * (freq2(A))
                float(a2) = (freq Pairs(GT)) - (freq1(G)) * (freq2(T))

  Expected Output:
                a1 = (1/3) - ((1/3)*(1/3)) = 0.222222
                a2 = (2/3) - ((2/3)*(2/3)) = 0.222222

  Error:     for base in list(i):  #dictionary
             TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

This is related to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066439/how-to-calculate-frequency-of-elements-for-pairwise-comparisons-of-lists-in-pyth)

Comment: ... and what is wrong with the code? If the gives an error please post the whole error message. If the output is not what you expect please provide the output you get, and what you'd like to receive instead.

Comment: @Bakuriu I have done the same

Comment: Also, I do not know how to write some parts of the code eg. #Insert code to calculate frequency of pairs - I do not know how to do this. So I need help in rectifying this code or new ways to write the code to the problem