# How to filter the list by selecting for unique combinations of characters in the elements (Python)?

Tags: python, list, unique, combinations

I have the the following pairs stored in the following list

```
 sample = [[CGCG,ATAT],[CGCG,CATC],[ATAT,TATA]]
```

Each pairwise comparison can have only two unique combinations of characters, if not then those pairwise comparisons are eliminated. eg,

```
   In sample[1]
    C       C
    G       A
    C       T 
    G       C
```

Look a the corresponding elements in both sub-lists, CC, GA, CT, GC.

Here, there are more than two types of pairs (CC), (GA), (CT) and (GC). So this pairwise comparison cannot occur.

Every comparison can have only 2 combinations out of (AA, GG,CC,TT, AT,TA,AC,CA,AG,GA,GC,CG,GT,TG,CT,TC) ... basically all possible combinations of ACGT where order matters.

In the above example, more than 2 such combinations are found.

However,

```
   In sample[0]
    C       A
    G       T
    C       A 
    G       T
```

There are only 2 unique combinations: CA and GT

Thus, the only pairs, that remain are:

```
output = [[CGCG,ATAT],[ATAT,TATA]]
```

I would prefer if the code was in traditional for-loop format and not comprehensions

This is a small part of the question listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066439/how-to-calculate-frequency-of-elements-for-pairwise-comparisons-of-lists-in-pyth/40073665?noredirect=1#comment67421103_40073665). This portion of the question is re-asked, as the answer provided earlier provided incorrect output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filter_sample(sample):
    filtered_sample = []

    for s1, s2 in sample:
        pairs = {pair for pair in zip(s1, s2)}
        if len(pairs) <= 2:
            filtered_sample.append([s1, s2])

    return filtered_sample
```

Running this

```
sample = [["CGCG","ATAT"],["CGCG","CATC"],["ATAT","TATA"]]
filter_sample(sample)
```

Returns this

```
[['CGCG', 'ATAT'], ['ATAT', 'TATA']]
```

Comment: You are right. I have corrected the sample, for clarification!

Comment: Cool, I updated my answer too to reflect the corrected sample.

Answer (score 1):

The core of this task is extracting the pairs from your sublists and counting the number of unique pairs.  Assuming your samples actually contain strings, you can use `zip(*sub_list)` to get the pairs.  Then you can use `set()` to remove duplicate entries.

```
sample = [['CGCG','ATAT'],['CGCG','CATC'],['ATAT','CATC']]

def filter(sub_list, n_pairs):
    pairs = zip(*sub_list)
    return len(set(pairs)) == n_pairs
```

Then you can use a for loop or a list comprehension to apply this function to your main list.

```
new_sample = [sub_list for sub_list in sample if filter(sub_list, 2)]
```

...or as a for loop...

```
new_sample = []
for sub_list in sample:
    if filter(sub_list, 2):
        new_sample.append(sub_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sample = [[CGCG,ATAT],[CGCG,CATC],[ATAT,CATC]]
result = []
for s in sample:
    first = s[0]
    second = s[1]
    combinations = []
    for i in range(0,len(first)):
        comb = [first[i],second[i]]
        if comb not in combinations:
            combinations.append(comb)
    if len(combinations) == 2:
        result.append(s)

print result
```