# How to calculate counts and frequencies for pairs in list of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

Bases refers to A,T,G and C

```
sample = [['CGG','ATT'],['GCGC','TAAA']]

# Note on fragility of data: Each element can only be made up only 2 of the 4 bases.  
# [['CGG' ==> Only C and G,'ATT' ==> Only A and T],['GCGC'==> Only C and G,'TAAA' ==> Only T and A]]
# Elements like "ATGG" are not present in the data as the have more than 3 different types of bases
```

Consider the first pair : ['CGG','ATT']

1. Calculate frequency of each base in the pairs separately:

   CGG => (C = 1/3, G = 2/3)
    ATT => (A = 1/3, T = 2/3)
2. Calculate frequency of occurrence of combination of bases in the pairs. Here, the combinations are 'CA' and 'GT' (Notice, order of the base matters. It is not 'CA','AC','GT' and 'TG'. Just only 'CA' and 'GT').

   Pairs => (CA = 1/3, GT = 2/3)
3. Calculate float(a) = (freq of Pairs) - ((freq of C in CGG) * (freq of A in ATT))

   Eg in CA pairs, float (a) = (freq of CA pairs) - ((freq of C in CGG) * (freq of A in ATT))

   Output a = (1/3) - ((1/3) * (1/3)) = 0.222222

Calculating "a" for any one combination (either CA pair or GT pair)

NOTE: If the pair is AAAC and CCCA, the freq of C would it be 1/4, i.e. it is the frequency of the base over one of the pairs

4. Calculate b
    float (b) = (float(a)^2)/ (freq of C in CGG) * (freq G in CGG) * (freq A in ATT) * (freq of T in ATT)

   ```
   Output b = 1
   ```

Do this for the entire list

```
   Final Output a = [0.2222, - 0.125]
                b = [1, 0.3333]
```

This code has been adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066439/how-to-calculate-frequency-of-elements-for-pairwise-comparisons-of-lists-in-pyth?noredirect=1#comment67422112_40066439). Please note that there are subtle differences in the two questions and they are NOT the same, in the approach to the problem.

However, I am unable to get this code to run. I get the following error:
   for pair, count in i:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
#Count individual bases.

sample4 = [['CGG','ATT'],['GCGC','TAAA']]
base_counter = Counter()
for i in enumerate(sample4):
    for pair, count in i:
        base_counter[pair[0]] += count
        base_counter[pair[1]] += count
        print base_counter

# Get the total for each base.
total_count = sum(base_counter.values())

# Convert counts to frequencies.
base_freq = {}
for base, count in base_counter.items():
    base_freq[base] = count / total_count
# Not sure how to write a code to count the number of pairs (Step 2)
# Let's say the counts have been stored in pair_counts

# Examine a pair from the two unique pairs to calculate float_a.
for i in enumerate(sample4):
    float(a) = (pair_count[pair] / sum(pair_count.values())) - (base_freq[pair[0]] * base_freq[pair[1]])

# Step 7!
for i in enumerate(sample4):
    float_b = float_a / float(base_freq[0][0] * base_freq[0][1] * base_freq[1][0] * base_freq[1][1])
```

Comment: `for j in i[0]:` ?? remove this line.

Comment: The way you are using `Counter` you might as well use a plain `dict`.

Comment: The `range` function returns a list of integers, so in your first loop each `i` is an `int`. Your error is because in the nested `for` loop you're trying to iterate over an `int`.

Maybe you want to use `enumerate` instead, or simply iterate over `sample4`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : Okay, I wil

Comment: @aiguofer It does not help

Comment: Notice, I still need help to write parts of the code, that I have put in the comments. I have put down the code here, so that community users can have a framework to help edit the code

Comment: @Biotechgeek, yeah... there's lots of other errors in your code. I think your time would be well spend looking up how loops work in python, and how `range` and `enumerate` work.

Also, this sort of things helps if you try to run line by line in REPL instead of trying to run the whole script at once. It lets you see what the output of each step is.

Comment: @aiguofer I am an amateur in python. I can run basic loops and functions, but i find it harder to work with list of lists and pairwise comparisons like this one. That's the reason I usually need help with longer loops

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using `Counter` any different than a plain `dict`. Try something like the following approach:

```
>>> sample = [['CGG','ATT'],['GCGC','TAAA']]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> base_counts = [[Counter(base) for base in sub] for sub in sample]
>>> base_counts
[[Counter({'G': 2, 'C': 1}), Counter({'T': 2, 'A': 1})], [Counter({'G': 2, 'C': 2}), Counter({'A': 3, 'T': 1})]]
```

Now you can continue with a functional approach using nested comprehensions to transform your data*:

```
>>> base_freqs = [[{k_v[0]:k_v[1]/len(bases[i]) for i,k_v in enumerate(count.items())} for count in counts] 
...               for counts, bases in zip(base_counts, sample)]
>>> 
>>> base_freqs
[[{'G': 0.6666666666666666, 'C': 0.3333333333333333}, {'A': 0.3333333333333333, 'T': 0.6666666666666666}], [{'G': 0.5, 'C': 0.5}, {'A': 0.75, 'T': 0.25}]]
>>>
```

*Note, some people do not like big, nested comprehensions like that. I think it's fine as long as you are sticking to functional constructs and not mutating data structures inside your comprehensions. I actually find it very expressive. Others disagree vehemently. You can always unfold that code into nested for-loops.

Anyway, you can then work the same thing with the pairs. First:

```
>>> pairs = [list(zip(*bases)) for bases in sample]
>>> pairs
[[('C', 'A'), ('G', 'T'), ('G', 'T')], [('G', 'T'), ('C', 'A'), ('G', 'A'), ('C', 'A')]]
>>> pair_counts = [Counter(base_pair) for base_pair in pairs]
>>> pair_counts
[Counter({('G', 'T'): 2, ('C', 'A'): 1}), Counter({('C', 'A'): 2, ('G', 'T'): 1, ('G', 'A'): 1})]
>>>
```

Now, here it is easier to not use comprehensions so we don't have to calculate `total` more than once:

```
>>> pair_freq = []
>>> for count in pair_counts:
...   total = sum(count.values())
...   pair_freq.append({k:c/total for k,c in count.items()})
... 
>>> pair_freq
[{('C', 'A'): 0.3333333333333333, ('G', 'T'): 0.6666666666666666}, {('G', 'T'): 0.25, ('C', 'A'): 0.5, ('G', 'A'): 0.25}]
>>>
```

Comment: However, if I use this method, I am not clear how I can extract the needed values and calculate value(s) of a. Step 3. Is this how you do it via comprehensions `float a = {k: float(pair_freq[k][0]) - base_freqs[k][0] * base_freqs[k][1]for k in pair_freq.viewkeys() & base_freqs.viewkeys()}`

Comment: Also, if it is alright..can you please break down base_freqs comprehension as a bunch of for-loops? I am relatively new to comprehensions and I find ti hard when I am trying to understand the logic of the code