# How to convert this comprehension to a for-loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, for-comprehension

```
sample = [['CGG','ATT'],['GCGC','TAAA']]
base_counts = [[Counter(base) for base in sub] for sub in sample]
#Output : [[Counter({'G': 2, 'C': 1}), Counter({'T': 2, 'A': 1})], [Counter({'C': 2, 'G': 2}), Counter({'A': 3, 'T': 1})]]

base_freqs = [[{k_v[0]:k_v[1]/len(bases[i]) for i,k_v in enumerate(count.items())} for count in counts] for counts, bases in zip(base_counts, sample)]
#Output 2 [[{'C': 0.3333333333333333, 'G': 0.6666666666666666}, {'A': 0.3333333333333333, 'T': 0.6666666666666666}], [{'C': 0.5, 'G': 0.5}, {'A': 0.75, 'T': 0.25}]]
```

The sample is the input and the Output2 is the final output of the program. The program with base_freqs, computes the frequency of "bases" (bases = ATGC) in each pair of the sample.  The output provides the correct answer. However, I would like to see the code in a for-loop format than comprehensions.

This code has been originally taken from the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40076570/6820344)

Comment: It would be great if someone could let me know how I could improve the question, than simply downvoting it.

Comment: Not downvoter, but it seems like your question lacks what the input and output of the code you provided. If you want someone to read and explain / give you a for loop example, why not make it easier for us to help you by telling us what it's suppose to do?

Comment: Stack Overflow is more suited to questions like *Here is the `for` loop-based reimplementation of this list comprehension. I expect it to yield `X` but it yields `Y` instead. Can you help?*, not to questions like *Is it possible to...*.

Comment: Also, I think it would be better to ask for an explanation from the person who posted this rather than ask a new set of people to analyse a piece of code without any context.

Comment: Reading the original question, Answer-er gave you a pretty good answer plus a none list comprehension version of the answer. If you are asking how does a list comprehension works, you might want to do some research first.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim I did, but he/she did not get back to me.

Comment: I think this is an ok question.  That's a pretty heavy duty list comprehension and getting a handle on the syntax for them can be a bit of a pain

Comment: @Patrick, showing their attempts at trying -- only trying -- to implement the `for` loop equivalent would have made this question okay. In its current state, it gives the usual "please do my work for me" vibe... but since everyone decided to upvote it, as well as a code-only answer without any explanation, I guess I'll have to let it pass...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks for your suggestions. I will keep in mind, to post my own attempts before posting this type of question in the future. Also, I assumed that once I read the for-loop code myself that I will be able to understand the logic. But mos who have answered have taken the effort to explain the shift from comprehensions to for-loop. Very grateful for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The way to read comprehensions in outside in and left to right.  Let's format it a little for readability:

```
base =[   
         [ 
             {   k_v[0] : k_v[1]/len(bases[i]) 
                 for i,k_v in enumerate(count.items())
             }  
             for count in counts
         ] 
         for counts, bases in zip(base_counts, sample) 
      ]
```

Is the same as:

```
bases = []
for counts, bases in zip(base_counts, sample):
    temp_list = []
    for count in counts:
        temp_dict = {}
        for i, k_v in enumerate(count.items()):
            temp_dict[k_v[0]] = k_v[1] / len(bases[i])
        temp_list.append(temp_dict)
    bases.append(temp_list)
```

The list comprehension is better from a performance standpoint because you aren't constantly creating new lists and dicts, or calling methods like append, which have some overhead.

Answer (score 2):

You can always translate a list comprehension such as

```
ls = [<EXPR> for <VARS> in <ITERABLE> if <CONDITIONAL>]
```

to

```
ls = []
for <VARS> in <ITERABLE>:
    if <CONDITIONAL>:
        ls.append(<EXPR>)
```

Multiple `for` clauses in the comprehension correspond to nested `for` loops in the translation, with the leftmost `for` clause corresponding to the outermost `for` loop.

Translations for generator, dict and set comprehensions are analogous.

Comment: inside the comprehension, `for` clauses to the left are read first.  `[a for a in (x,y) for x, y in [(1,2), (3,4)]]` Fails because the interpreter sees `x` before it is defined

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Argh, you're right. I noticed I made an error ten seconds before I saw your comment. As luck would have it, I actually thought to myself how I should take care not to mess it up as I was writing the answer but I managed to do it anyway. :D Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really easier with for loop, but here is how it should look like.

```
result = []
for counts, bases in zip(base_counts, sample):
    some_list = []
    for count in counts:
        some_dict = {}
        for i,k_v in enumerate(count.items()):
            some_dict[k_v[0]] = k_v[1]/len(bases[i])
        some_list.append(some_dict)
    result.append(some_list)
```