# Frequency of elements in pairwise comparison of lists within a list in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, frequency, pairwise

I have a list of lists like this:

```
my_list_of_lists = 
[['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','junco','jay','robin'],
['sparrow','sparrow','junco', 'sparrow','robin','robin'],
['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','jay','robin']]
```

I would like to do a pairwise comparison at each position for all lists with the list like this:

```
#1 with 2
['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','junco','jay','robin']
['sparrow','sparrow','junco', 'sparrow','robin','robin']

#1 with 3
['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','junco','jay','robin']
['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','jay','robin']

#2 with 3
['sparrow','sparrow','junco', 'sparrow','robin','robin']
['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','jay','robin']
```

So the pairs for the 1 with 2:

```
pairs =[('sparrow','sparrow'), ('sparrow','sparrow'), ('sparrow','junco'),('junco','sparrow'),('junco','junco'), ('jay','robin'), ('robin','robin')]
```

I would like to get the counts and frequency of the pairs in each pairwise comparison:

```
pairs =[('sparrow','sparrow'), ('sparrow','sparrow'), ('sparrow','junco'),('junco','sparrow') ('junco','junco'), ('jay','robin'), ('robin','robin')]

sparrowsparrow_counts = 2
juncosparrow_counts = 2
jayrobin_counts = 1
robinrobin = 1

frequency_of_combos = [('sparrow', 'sparrow'):.333, ('sparrow', 'junco'):.333, ('jay', 'robin'):.167, ('robin', 'robin'): .167]
```

I've tried zipping but I end up zipping all of the lists (not the pairs) into tuples and I'm stumped on the rest.

I think it's somewhat related to [How to calculate counts and frequencies for pairs in list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076241/how-to-calculate-counts-and-frequencies-for-pairs-in-list-of-lists?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I can't figure out how to apply this to my data.

Comment: You zip a pair of dicts; use the `collections.Counter` structure to count the pairs.  Divide by the total.  Now repeat that for each of the three list pairings.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. To make sure I'm understanding you correctly, I would create a dictionary of these lists (so a dictionary of lists) and then use the collections.Counter to count pairs for each pairwise comparison of each list. Dividing by the total will give me the frequency. As for repeating, in the full dataset, I do have to iterate over about 75 of these lists, so I would loop through the dictionary. Is this a correct interpretation?

Comment: Sorry -- zip a pair of the three *lists*, not new dicts.  If you have 75 of the lists, then I recommend you use `itertools.combinations(list_of_lists, 2)` to generate the list pairings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip the two lists, then filter out the pairs that don't match, and use collections.Counter to count them:

```
from collections import Counter

a = ['sparrow','sparrow','sparrow','junco','jay','robin']
b = ['sparrow','sparrow','junco', 'sparrow','robin','robin']
c = Counter([ i for i in zip(a,b) if i[0] == i[1]])
print(c)


Counter({('sparrow', 'sparrow'): 2, ('robin', 'robin'): 1})
```

You seem to have the frequency part figured out, but that should clear up the use of zip and Counter.